# What is the change I need to make to perform reverse of upper_bound?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I feel `lower_bound` in c++ stl is not the opposite of the `upper_bound` function. By default, in a non-decreasing array, if I use `upper_bound` and if the element is found and it is not the last element in the sorted array, then the next element > passed element is given and if the element is then last element or not found, then `end()` iterator returned. The following C++ code can be used to test this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  vector<int> arr{-973, -808, -550, 301, 414, 897};
  auto p = upper_bound (arr.begin (), arr.end (), 301);
  if (p != arr.end ())
    cout << *p << endl;
  else
    cout << "end" << endl;
  return 0;
}
// Output: 414
```

But now I need the opposite thing. I need the smaller element from the matched element to be returned. In the above example, if I pass `301`, then, I want to get `-550` in return. Currently, I am using the following code and it seems to work for the given example but I am not sure if it is the right code or I need to implement it manually using binary search.

`auto p = upper_bound(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), 301,  greater<int>());`

PS. I am using if `(p != arr.rend ())` for this.

Comment: `reverse_iterator` should work, no need to reimplement that yourself..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` is what you want here.  `lower_bound` returns the first element that is equal to or greater than the input provided.  Knowing that, if you do

```
auto p = lower_bound(arr.begin (), arr.end (), 301);
```

then `p` will be at the `301`, and subtracting `1` from it will give you element `-550`.  So, you just need to check before you do that subtraction that `p != arr.begin()`.  If it is, then the subtraction will work.  If it isn't, then there is no element less then the input passed to `lower_bound`.  That gives you something like

```
auto p = lower_bound(arr.begin (), arr.end (), input_value);
if (p == arr.begin())
    std::cout << "no element found less than " << input_value;
else
    std::cout << "first element less than " << input_value << " is " << *std::prev(p);
```

Comment: Great..Thanks for it however I was looking something more cleaner. What about the snippet I provided ?

Comment: This is equivalent to what's in the question, but `std::reverse_iterator` hides the -1. For that reason I prefer it.

Comment: @Caleth `but std::reverse_iterator hides the -1` Can you please elaborate this a little more?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar It holds an iterator [one past](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) what it dereferences to, and does the [equivalent of `prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator*) in the dereference